# Shell Scripting Python Shell imports

Tags: python, django, sh

I'd like to save myself some typing when I'm testing things in `python manage.py shell`. Basically I have a little shell script that gets me into the `>>>` shell, but I'd like to be able to automatically push in the import calls in my views.py script so I don't have to type them every time I want to test something. I tried writing them out in the shell script but it seems that they weren't passed to python shell.

Here's what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
python ~/path/to/manage.py shell

import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from mymodel.models import *
from myapp.forms import *
... and so on
```

What I'd like to happen is for all the import lines to be pushed into python shell so I don't have to type/copy-paste them everytime I want to debug at the shell.

Comment: 3 mins, 3 answers. Nice response rate for a Friday night.

Comment: Only the true geeks are out this late on a Friday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also django-extensions: http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/11/17/preloading-stuff-in-djangos-interactive-shell/

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly - you would just call `python manage.py shell-plus.py`?

Comment: That is just one of the command extensions. That particular command will autoload models. Check out: http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/command_extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

Put your prequel into a file. Here, I'll assume it's in a file appropriately named `prequel`. Then you can adjust your bash script like so:

```
cat prequel - | python ~/path/to/manage.py shell
```

`cat` concatenates files, but it can treat standard input as a file, so we're concatenating your prequel and then standard input and then piping that concatenation to the shell.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could use `cat` to do that.

Comment: I think this works. I say I think because the `>>>` doesn't show up, yet it seems when I type something, I am in fact in the shell.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: I'm guessing it won't print `>>>` unless it detects its standard input is a tty. If it's a pipe from `cat` (even if `cat` is getting its input from a tty), it's still a pipe and not a tty, so it won't print the `>>>`. I guess this is why that Django extension thing would be better. (It can execute stuff on its own without messing with standard input.)